# Getting the correct position of an instantiated prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

When my game starts, I'm instantiating a prefab several times:

```
for (int y = 0; y < gridY; y++) {
  for (int x = 0; x < gridX; x++) {
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (x, 0, y) * spacing;
    Instantiate(prefab, pos, Quaternion.identity);
  }
}
```

This works fine - the objects are displayed correctly in the scene.

The prefab got a script attached, which prints the objects position to the debug output when you right click it. The problem I'm facing is that all these prefabs are returning the same position?

--edit

This is the code I use to print the coordinates:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) {
        Debug.Log(transform.position.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code? Maybe you are using localPosition of some GameObject in the prefab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Valentin. I have added the code I'm using to get the position to my question.

Comment: The coordinates I get are the ones of the last prefab instanciated.

Comment: Set all prefabs different names and add a `Log` to `Update` of the script to log name and position of objects every frame. See if they are identical or not.

Comment: Funny thing, I copied the code (transform.position...) from Update() to OnMouseOver() and everything works fine. Thanks again for your help Valentin.